# (sql plus) how to alias column

Tags: sqlplus

I've been trying to use aliases to change column names

I have three tables : name , member and payment

I took two different syntax from the internet and I tried them both

first one:

```
SELECT n.firstname AS [First Name], n.lastname AS [Last Name], m.username AS UserName,
       m.birthday AS Birthday, m.email AS Email, m.phone_no AS Phone, 
       p.MembershipType AS [Membership Type]
FROM member AS m, name AS n, payment AS p
WHERE (m.username = n.username) and (m.username = p.username)
ORDER by n.firstname;
```

second one:

```
SELECT n.firstname 'First Name', n.lastname 'Last Name', m.username 
       'UserName', m.birthday 'Birthday',
        m.email 'Email', m.phone_no 'Phone', p.MembershipType 'Membership Type'
FROM member m, name n, payment p
WHERE (m.username = n.username) and (m.username = p.username)
ORDER by n.firstname;
```

But it display "FROM keyword not found where expected" 
what did I do wrong?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF00223

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using **Oracle** database.

If the alias_name contains spaces, you must enclose the alias_name in **quotes**

So your query might look like:

```
SELECT n.firstname "First Name", n.lastname "Last Name", m.username 
       "UserName", m.birthday "Birthday",
        m.email "Email", m.phone_no "Phone", p.MembershipType "Membership Type"
FROM member m, name n, payment p
WHERE (m.username = n.username) and (m.username = p.username)
ORDER by n.firstname;
```